# Make command run when MySQL database connection is made

Tags: server, mysql, lamp, execute-command, joomla

I have successfully set up an AMP server (Apache, MySQL, and PHP) and have installed my Content Management System (Joomla!), which I am using to make a small website. The CMS connects to MySQL whenever someone connects to the site to get the page. However, I want to make a command run (yes, a normal GNU/Linux command, not a MySQL command) run whenever a database connection is made. I don't care if this means modifying a MySQL server setting or running a script on a forever loop that checks for database connections (which I am willing to do). How would I go about doing this? Thanks. (P.S. The system is running MySQL 5.5.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are better solutions, and i don't know if this would be an optimal solution for you, but one way to accomplish this would be to simply call `shell_exec()` after each `mysqli_connect()`:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'db');
shell_exec('<command>');
```